# Get rows above and below (neighbouring rows) a certain row, based on two criteria SQL

Tags: php, join, mariadb, union

Say I have a table like so:

```
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
|id | level |score |      timestamp      |
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
| 4 |   1   |  70  | 2021-01-14 21:50:38 |
| 3 |   1   |  90  | 2021-01-12 15:38:0  |
| 1 |   1   |  20  | 2021-01-14 13:10:12 |
| 5 |   1   |  50  | 2021-01-13 12:32:11 |
| 7 |   1   |  50  | 2021-01-14 17:15:20 |
| 8 |   1   |  55  | 2021-01-14 09:20:00 |
| 10|   2   |  99  | 2021-01-15 10:50:38 |
| 2 |   1   |  45  | 2021-01-15 10:50:38 |
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
```

What I want to do is show 5 of these rows in a table (in html), with a certain row (e.g. where id=5) in the middle and have the two rows above and below it (in the correct order). Also where level=1. This will be like a score board but only showing the user's score with the two above and two below.
So because scores can be the same, the timestamp column will also need to be used - so if two scores are equal, then the first person to get the score is shown above the other person.

E.g. say the user is id=5, I want to show

```
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
|id | level |score |      timestamp      |
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
| 4 |   1   |  70  | 2021-01-14 21:50:38 |
| 8 |   1   |  55  | 2021-01-14 09:20:00 |
| 5 |   1   |  50  | 2021-01-13 12:32:11 |
| 7 |   1   |  50  | 2021-01-14 17:15:20 |
| 2 |   1   |  45  | 2021-01-15 10:50:38 |
| 1 |   1   |  20  | 2021-01-14 13:10:12 |
+---+-------+------+---------------------+
```

Note that id=7 is below id=5

I am wondering does anyone know a way of doing this?

I have tried this below but it is not outputting what I need (it is outputting where level_id=2 and id=5, and the other rows are not in order)

```
((SELECT b.* FROM table a JOIN table b ON b.score > a.score OR (b.score = a.score AND b.timestamp < a.timestamp)
  WHERE a.level_id = 1 AND a.id = 5 ORDER BY score ASC, timestamp DESC LIMIT 3)
 UNION ALL 
 (SELECT b.* FROM table a JOIN table b ON b.score < a.score OR (b.score = a.score AND b.timestamp > a.timestamp)
  WHERE a.level_id = 1 AND a.id = 5 ORDER BY score DESC, timestamp ASC LIMIT 2)) 
order by score
```

If it is easier to output all rows in the table, say where level = 1, so it is a full score board.. and then do the getting a certain row and two above and below it using PHP I'd also like to know please :) ! (possibly thinking this may keep the SQL simpler)?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What your DB version?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev MariaDB .. is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when id = 7 then score_rank end) over () as id_rank
      from (select t.*,
                   dense_rank() over (order by score) as score_rank
            from t
            where level = 1
           ) t
     ) t
where score_rank between id_rank - 2 and id_rank + 2;
```

Note:  This returns 5 distinct score values, which may result in more rows depending on duplicates.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c31944c6838815f92fa3804863687fed) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want exactly 5 rows using the timestamp, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when id = 7 then score_rank end) over () as id_rank
      from (select t.*,
                   dense_rank() over (order by score, timestamp) as score_rank
            from t
            where level = 1
           ) t
     ) t
where score_rank between id_rank - 2 and id_rank + 2
order by score;
```

Note:  This still treats equivalent timestamps as the same, but they seem to be unique in your data.

Comment: Hi, although I have no idea what that code means, I tried it and it's returning zero rows

Comment: @bb25 . . . I fixed a typo and added a db<>fiddle.  It works.

Comment: This gives the users with equal scores the same rank - but my reasoning behind using a timestamp is to allow them to have different rankings. ie. the person who got the score first is higher ranking

Comment: The edited answer doesn't seem to be working. I am getting values where level = 2 (which i don't want). Also the rows are in a mixed up order

Comment: If you only want `level = 1`, then use a `where` clause.

Comment: It is getting the scores from lowest-highest so I added `DESC` to the very end of the sql, and it orders the scores the way I need them (highest-lowest) but then gives the ranks the wrong way around (5-1) instead of (1-5)

Comment: sorry for bothering you, but is there a way this can be done using basic mySQL operators? I am not using SQL server and not sure I feel comfortable using those windows functions..

Comment: @bb25 . . . This is standard SQL and supported by MariaDB and most other databases.  As for the ranks, your question doesn't even include them.  But you can change to using `score desc` for the ranking as well.

Comment: Oh great. Yeah I know it doesn't include them but now that they're in your answer I'd like to include them :) I have done`order by score desc, score_rank` at the end but it still has the ranks going from 5-1 instead of 1-5

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte and inner join as follows:

```
With cte as
(select t.*,
        dense_rank() over (order by score) as dr
   from your_table t)
Select c.*
  From cte c join cte cu on c.dr between cu.dr - 2 and cu.dr + 2
 Where cu.id = 5
Ordwr by c.dr, c.timestamp
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error `Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)`

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: MariaDB is that what you mean? (sorry not fully sure what you mean by 'what database')

Comment: MySQL prior to version 8.0 doesn't support the WITH clause.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this using standard SQL?